# Powershell Select node by String value

Tags: xml, powershell

I`m trying to select one node, by string value of another node.

My Xml part:

```
          <XIP xmlns="http://prty/XIP/v6.0">
             <Generation>
               <Properties>
                 <Property>
                   <PUID>prp/10008</PUID>
                   <PropertyName>Number Of Audio Streams</PropertyName>
                   <Value>1</Value>
                 </Property>
                <Property>
                  <PUID>prp/12</PUID>
                  <PropertyName>Sampling Frequency</PropertyName>
                  <Value>48000</Value>
                </Property>
                <Property>
                  <PUID>prp/10002</PUID>
                  <PropertyName>Duration</PropertyName>
                  <Value>2M9.686S</Value>
                </Property>
             <Properties>
          <Generation>
        </XIP>
```

So, the idea is get 2M9.686S, by string Duration

```
$xmlDocument.XIP.Generation.Properties.Property.Value |  Where-Object $xmlDocument.XIP.Generation.Properties.Property -Property PropertyName -Like ("Duration")
```

I'm trying for different ways, but don't return any value. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Xml has errors no </Properties> or </Generation>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate like this:

`$xmlDocument.XIP.Generation.Properties.Property | where {$_.PropertyName -eq "Duration"}`

to access to the specific Property and the followint to access to the Value, ie:

```bsh
($xmlDocument.XIP.Generation.Properties.Property |
    where {$_.PropertyName -eq "Duration"}).value
```

(For replicate the scenario, I used the `$xmlDocument = [xml](Get-Content .\test.xml)` to save and access to the XML content)

Comment: Thank you! I think that actually exist another best approach, but if it works, perfect!

Comment: You don't need the backquote, a pipe can continue a line, among a lot of other things.

Comment: Thanks js2010, i try your solution and works fine to!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the xpath version.  The namespace adds a little complication.  The double quotes are required, otherwise the pattern looks like an array.

```
$ns = @{x = 'http://prty/XIP/v6.0'}
select-xml "//*[x:PropertyName='Duration']" file.xml -Namespace $ns | 
  % {$_.node.value}

2M9.686S
```